# Change a div size on right-click hold and drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to make a div resizable on right-click hold and drag.

What I want is a mouse's right-click to change a div's dimentions on drag.

I have a problem which seems like to be that the previous size of the div is not updated.
On the second attempt to drag the div, it starts with it's previous state.

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // right click event
  $("#displayWindow")
    // when the mouse is pressed, the div is appended to the displayWindow
    .mousedown(function(e) {
      if (e.button == 2) {
        $('#div1').remove();
        // append the div start at the location that we click
        $("#displayWindow").append("<div id='div1'></div>");
        // get the coordinate where we clicked and set the div begin with that position
        var clickedX = e.pageX;
        var clickedY = e.pageY;
        $('#div1').css('top', clickedY);
        $('#div1').css('left', clickedX);

        // holding on the mouse button, change the size of the div
        $("#displayWindow").on("mousemove", function(e) {
          if (e.button == 2) {
            var mouseOnX = e.pageX;
            var mouseOnY = e.pageY;
            // allow user drag the selection box in 4 different direction
            if (mouseOnX > clickedX && mouseOnY > clickedY) {
              $('#div1').css('top', clickedY);
              $('#div1').css('left', clickedX);
              $('#div1').css('height', mouseOnY - clickedY);
              $('#div1').css('width', mouseOnX - clickedX);
            } else if (clickedX > mouseOnX && mouseOnY > clickedY) {
              $('#div1').css('top', clickedY);
              $('#div1').css('left', mouseOnX);
              $('#div1').css('height', mouseOnY - clickedY);
              $('#div1').css('width', clickedX - mouseOnX);
            } else if (clickedX > mouseOnX && clickedY > mouseOnY) {
              $('#div1').css('top', mouseOnY);
              $('#div1').css('left', mouseOnX);
              $('#div1').css('height', clickedY - mouseOnY);
              $('#div1').css('width', clickedX - mouseOnX);
            } else if (mouseOnX > clickedX && clickedY > mouseOnY) {
              $('#div1').css('top', mouseOnY);
              $('#div1').css('left', clickedX);
              $('#div1').css('height', clickedY - mouseOnY);
              $('#div1').css('width', mouseOnX - clickedX);
            }
          }
        }); // end on, while we move the mouse
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });

  // when clicked again, the menu fade out, and the div disappear
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.button == 0) {
      // remove the selection box div
      $('#div1').remove();
    }
  });

  // prevent the default contextmenu on the display window
  document.getElementById('displayWindow').oncontextmenu = function() {
    return false;
  }

}); // end ready
```

```css
#displayWindow {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="displayWindow">
  <svg height="130" width="150" style="position:absolute; left:200; top:200;" class="ui-widget-content">
    <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>
    <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue">
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this inside the `if (e.button == 2) {`. To reset the element added previously.

```
$('#div1').removeAttr('style').remove();
```

```js
// right click event
  $("#displayWindow")
    // when the mouse is pressed, the div is appended to the displayWindow
    .mousedown(function(e) {
      if (e.button == 2) {
        $('#div1').removeAttr('style').remove();
        // append the div start at the location that we click
        $("#displayWindow").append("<div id='div1'></div>");
        // get the coordinate where we clicked and set the div begin with that position
        var clickedX = e.pageX;
        var clickedY = e.pageY;
        $('#div1').css('top', clickedY);
        $('#div1').css('left', clickedX);

        // holding on the mouse button, change the size of the div
        $("#displayWindow").on("mousemove", function(e) {
          if (e.button == 2) {
            var mouseOnX = e.pageX;
            var mouseOnY = e.pageY;
            // allow user drag the selection box in 4 different direction
            if (mouseOnX > clickedX && mouseOnY > clickedY) {
              $('#div1').css('top', clickedY);
              $('#div1').css('left', clickedX);
              $('#div1').css('height', mouseOnY - clickedY);
              $('#div1').css('width', mouseOnX - clickedX);
            } else if (clickedX > mouseOnX && mouseOnY > clickedY) {
              $('#div1').css('top', clickedY);
              $('#div1').css('left', mouseOnX);
              $('#div1').css('height', mouseOnY - clickedY);
              $('#div1').css('width', clickedX - mouseOnX);
            } else if (clickedX > mouseOnX && clickedY > mouseOnY) {
              $('#div1').css('top', mouseOnY);
              $('#div1').css('left', mouseOnX);
              $('#div1').css('height', clickedY - mouseOnY);
              $('#div1').css('width', clickedX - mouseOnX);
            } else if (mouseOnX > clickedX && clickedY > mouseOnY) {
              $('#div1').css('top', mouseOnY);
              $('#div1').css('left', clickedX);
              $('#div1').css('height', clickedY - mouseOnY);
              $('#div1').css('width', mouseOnX - clickedX);
            }
          }
        }); // end on, while we move the mouse
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });

  // when clicked again, the menu fade out, and the div disappear
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.button == 0) {
      // remove the selection box div
      $('#div1').remove();
    }
  });

  // prevent the default contextmenu on the display window
  document.getElementById('displayWindow').oncontextmenu = function() {
    return false;
  }
```

```css
#displayWindow {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 400px;
  width: 800px;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="displayWindow">
  <svg height="130" width="150" style="position:absolute; left:200; top:200;" class="ui-widget-content">
    <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>
    <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" fill="none" stroke="blue" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I think the problem still remain. I am not sure if it is the previous location cause the problem. It seems like sometimes when I drag the second box, it creates unwanted size of box, and just disappear for just a moment,

Comment: @tiger I am not sure why, but it looks like some css properties are persisiting, but not how. Try this `$('#div1').removeAttr('style').remove();`